# Your webpage is using 30 inline CSS styles

Tags: google-web-designer

How do I get rid of them? I made a website in WordPress using a Sidney theme and i am trying to optimize it. I am using an online SEO score checker and it gives me this message as an error: Your web page is using 30 inline CSS styles. How can I change that?